# Why C# fire and forget is not working with http call in an API?

Tags: c#, async-await, minimal-apis

I have two minimal APIs, the receiver one is simple

```
var app = builder.Build();
app.MapGet("/testing", () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Received");
});
app.Run();
```

The calling API returns 200 but does not make the call:

```
var app = builder.Build();
app.MapGet("/call", () =>
{
     using var client = new HttpClient();
     client.GetAsync("http://localhost:5215/testing");
});
app.Run();
```

But this one is returning 200 and after 5 seconds making call, why?

```
var app = builder.Build();
app.MapGet("/call", () =>
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        using var client = new HttpClient();
        await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:5215/testing");
    });
});
app.Run();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your client gets disposed before the request has the chance to go anywhere:

```
() =>
{
    using var client = new HttpClient();
    client.GetAsync("http://localhost:5215/testing");
}
```

See that `using`? When execution leaves the scope, the client gets disposed. This aborts all current requests. If you were awaiting the `GetAsync`, then the client would only get disposed after the response has been received.

Comment: It should be noted that invoking GetAsync without awaiting is problematic. There's no guarantee that it will complete successfully by the time the calling method is done executing, and any exceptions thrown will be lost. True fire and forget is generally not desirable.

Comment: @user33276346: It also should be noted that disposing of `HttpClient` instances is a very bad idea. Looking up HttpClient and Dispose and IHttpClientFactory should help you find discussion about this

Comment: @Flydog57 Well, disposing `HttpClient` instances when you're done with them is a very good idea, and you should do it. What is a bad idea is creating new temporary clients per request. But even if you use `IHttpClientFactory` you should _still_ be disposing your clients.

Comment: Using the client like in the answer works, injecting the client with Dependency Injection does not work with AddHttpClient nor with SocketsHttpHandler, I guess it is not developed correctly to handle fire and forget scenarios for files.

Comment: "HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and reused throughout the life of an application." _from_ 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client#create-and-initialize-httpclient